# Java swing JScrollPane not scrollable

Tags: java, swing

[This is the add(main) version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwruR.png)

[This is the add(scroll) version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erCQd.png)

Im trying to get a window full of lables and make it scrollable, this is my code for that purpose:

```
public class JobHistoryListScreen extends JFrame implements View
{

    @Override
    public void showScreen()
    {
        setSize(800, 800);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setSize(500,500);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setSize(500,500);

        //Font
        //Font david50 = new Font("David", Font.BOLD, 50);

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            JLabel empty = new JLabel("No jobs to display!");
            empty.setBounds(0,i+250,400,100);
            empty.setFont(david50);
            main.add(empty);
        }
        add(main);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JobHistoryListScreen v = new JobHistoryListScreen();
        v.showScreen();
    }
}
```

For some reason the window gets filled with the labels but is not scrollable at all.

Comment: You didn't add your scroll pane to the frame. You added `main` directly.

Comment: 1) `setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). **A `null` layout will also make scroll panes fail.** 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: .. 3) `main.setSize(800,800);` this is too big for an 800 x 800 frame, which also has a title bar and (on most systems) a couple of pixels along the left, right and bottom. 4) Swing & AWT GUIs should be started and updated on the EDT. 5) `Font david50 = new Font("David", Font.BOLD, 50);` Don't set custom fonts when trying to work out layout issues. Also don't assume they are available unless they are distributed with the app. and the code explicitly loads them. 6) Don't extend a frame or component unless it is actually required. There is nothing in that code that requires a custom frame.

Comment: @AndrewThompson changed my code, nothing changed regarding the scrollable issue.

Comment: As suggested by @khelwood, change `add(main);` to `add(scroll);`!

Comment: I did and it shows a scroll bar on the right side of the screen but all the labels appear at the top row one after the other instead of showing up below each other.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about layout managers. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Default for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` and because the `JPanel` is inside a `JScrollPanel`, the labels will not wrap. And since you set the horizontal scroll bar policy to NEVER, there is no horizontal scroll bar and hence you cannot scroll horizontally. Try using `BoxLayout` to display all the labels one under the other. Alternatively you could use a `GridLayout` with 0 (zero) rows and 1 (one) column. Refer to the tutorial for more details.

### EDIT

Here is my modified version of your code. Explanatory notes appear after the code.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JobHistoryListScreen implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showScreen();
    }

    public void showScreen() {
        frame = new JFrame("Jobs");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main,
                                             JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                             JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        Font david50 = new Font("David", Font.BOLD, 50);
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            JLabel empty = new JLabel("No jobs to display!");
            empty.setFont(david50);
            main.add(empty);
        }
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JobHistoryListScreen v = new JobHistoryListScreen();

        // Launch Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)
        EventQueue.invokeLater(v);
    }
}
```

- I don't know what interface `View` is so I removed that part.
- No need to extend class `JFrame`.
- No need to explicitly call `setSize()` on `JFrame`. Better to call `pack()`.
- Default content pane for `JFrame` is `JPanel` and default layout manager for that `JPanel` is `BorderLayout` so no need to explicitly set.
- No need to call `setSize()` on `JPanel`.
- Call `setPreferredSize()` rather than `setSize()` on `JScrollPane`.
- Add the `JScrollPane` to the `JFrame` and not the `JPanel`.
- No need to call `setBounds()` because `GridLayout` handles this.
- Explicitly launch EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) by calling `invokeLater()`.

Here is a screen capture of the running app. Note the vertical scroll bar.

[image: jobslist.png]

Comment: Tnx for the comment, Ive tried using both Box and Grid layouts and nither gave me the option to scroll.


The never for horizontal and always for vertical scrolls is intentional.